# Can't extract reference from HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I managed to scrape the following data from a website, but am unable to go further with scraping the reference of images on each page. Let me illustrate:

```
data = """
<div class="Answer">
1. Origin (O): <i>clavicular head -&nbsp;</i>sternal half of clavicle. <i>Sternal head -&nbsp;</i>sternum down to 7th rib &amp; cartilages of true ribs &amp; aponeurosis of EXTERNAL OBLIQUE.<div>2. Insertion (I): lateral lip of intertubercular sulcus of humerus <b><i>(TIP: 1 missus [LATISSIMUS DORSI] b/w 2 majors [PECTORALIS MAJOR &amp; TERES MAJOR])</i></b></div><div>3. NS: medial &amp; lateral pectoral n.&nbsp;</div><div>4. A: adducts &amp; internally rotates arm; flexes shoulder.&nbsp;</div><div><img src="paste-7450347406b71a5e5c2e6dc2442ca630347acc64.jpg"><br></div><div><b>Image:&nbsp;</b>Gray, Henry. <i>Anatomy of the Human Body.</i> Philadelphia: Lea &amp; Febiger, 1918; Bartleby.com, 2000. <a href="https://www.bartleby.com/107/">www.bartleby.com/107/</a>&nbsp;[Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].</div>
</div>
<div class="Answer">
1. O: outer, upper surface of ribs 3-5.&nbsp;<div>2. I: corocoid process of scapula.&nbsp;</div><div>3. NS: medial pectoral n.</div><div>4. A: lowers the lateral angle &amp; protracts the scapula.&nbsp;</div><div><br></div><div><img src="paste-fbab2e102740a7713816f498946f8cd977010c8f.gif"><br></div><div><b>Image:</b>&nbsp;Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52195"&gt;rID: 52195&lt;/a&gt;</div>
</div>
"""
```

From this data I need the references after the 'Image:', that is, I need:

```
Gray, Henry. <i>Anatomy of the Human Body.</i> Philadelphia: Lea &amp; Febiger, 1918; Bartleby.com, 2000. <a href="https://www.bartleby.com/107/">www.bartleby.com/107/</a>&nbsp;[Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].

Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52195"&gt;rID: 52195&lt;/a&gt;
```

I need to insert the two references back into another HTML page. 
I tried this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
Answers = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"Answer"})
for answer in Answers:
    if answer.find('b').next == 'Image:': image_link = BeautifulSoup(answer.find('b').next.next, 'html.parser')
    else: image_link = "no link"
```

But it doesn't work, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure it's not a smart code but i think it will be help`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
Answers = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"Answer"})
for answer in Answers:
   regex1 = r"<div><b>.*?</b>"
   regex2 = r"</div>"
   subst = ""
   if answer.find_all('b')[-1].next.strip() == 'Image:':
       parent_element = answer.find_all('b')[-1].parent
       result = re.sub(regex1, subst, str(parent_element))
       image_link = re.sub(regex2, subst, str(result))
   else: 
       image_link = "no link"

print(image_link)
```

Comment: Good solution, but what does `enter code here` mean?

Comment: I was a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for that! There are still some references which begin with "<div><span style="font-weight: bolder;">Image:</span>" How could I cover for that?

Comment: You can use another regex `regex3 = r"<div.*?</span>" `.
You see this site to regex operation. [https://regex101.com]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
img_links = soup.select('div.Answer b')

for el in img_links:
    print(''.join(map(repr, el.next_siblings)))
```

The output:

```
'Gray, Henry. '<i>Anatomy of the Human Body.</i>' Philadelphia: Lea & Febiger, 1918; Bartleby.com, 2000. '<a href="https://www.bartleby.com/107/">www.bartleby.com/107/</a>'\xa0[Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].'
'\xa0Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/">Radiopaedia.org</a>. From the case <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52195">rID: 52195</a>'
```

Comment: But it loses all HTML info. I need to insert the two references back into another HTML page.

Comment: @CodeMonkey, that was not clear from your initial description. Update your question with appropriate details